# How to disable Fujifilm X-M1 screen?

Tags: viewfinder, fujifilm, live-view

The X-M1 does not come with a EVF (electronic view finder). In the interest of saving a lot of battery power I am hoping to use an [external viewfinder](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/35mm-Viewfinder-for-Leica-Voigtlander-Zorki-Fed-Contax-Canon-Kiev-/161229256862?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item258a03389e) as an alternative to the absent EVF. This is only going to save power if one is able to switch-off the live-view display (or at least dim the backlight to nearly being black).

**Is there a way of disabling, or severely dimming the X-M1 screen?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fuji X-M1's LCD is adjustable and the lowest intensity is indeed quite dark. There is no way to disable it completely though as Fuji probably expects the camera to be useless without it. Keep in mind that the best increase in battery-life is achieved by not using the built-in flash.

Comment: To improve battery life, I would expect other options should be to disable fast-start.